# Why are no matches found when ever regex char optional

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'm very puzzled about why this is happening, and hoping someone can explain the mechanics of what is happening in the regex engine.

Whilst working on codewars exercise "Did you mean...?" in Javascript, I was trying to calculate how many of the characters in word1 appear in word2. I'm attempting to match with each char as its own match group, so that later on I can count the number of successful matches in the array, and use that to find out how similar the two words are.

Please don't give me tips on how to solve the codewars challenge, just help me understand what is going on here.

I tried:

```
'berry'.match(/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y?)/)
```

and got no matches

```
> ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

This is a mystery to me. Having searched Regular-expressions.info, the `?` (make preceding character optional) is greedy, so although no matches is valid for the regex, shouldn't it be trumped by the greedy version first? I was expecting this:

```
> ["", "", "", "e", "r", "r", "y"]
```

Other things I have tried:
- cherry match cherry works as I expected

```
'cherry'.match(/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y?)/)
> ["cherry", "c", "h", "e", "r", "r", "y"]
```

cherl match cherry works as I would expect too

```
'cherl'.match(/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y?)/)
> ["cher", "c", "h", "e", "r", "", ""]
```

And if I remove the `?` from the final `y`, it also works as expected:

```
'berry'.match(/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y)/)
> ["erry", "", "", "e", "r", "r", "y"]
```

So why does adding a `?` onto the final `y` mean I no longer see any matched characters?

Although I have tried this in JS, I get the same in PY and PCRE

Comment: `?` means one or none and is **always** true - finding nothing is considered a match. It is greedy insofar as it tries to find something first (instead of the opposite lazy quantifier: try to be satisfied with *nothing*).

Comment: You did not use `/g` in JS, thus you got one match: empty location in the beginning of the string. Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY9tG8/2)

Comment: Thanks Jan, Wiktor - in particular Wiktor - that makes sense. So the regex engine works from left to right on the string trying to match, and without the `g` flag it finds a match of zero chars at the very start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why does adding a `?` onto the final y mean I no longer see any matched characters?

The pattern you have used in the beginning - `/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y?)/` - *can match an empty string* because all the subpatterns are optional (i.e. can match zero occurrences). When you are looking for just one match (say, with `String#match` in JavaScript), you will always get the match that is at the very beginning of the string (because in most cases, a regex engine analyzes the string from left to right), either an empty string (if the first character cannot be matched the first subpattern) or some substring if the leading or all subpatterns matched.

So, `berry` starts with `b`. The `/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y?)/` starts with optional `c`, thus, `b` cannot be matched with `c` and it fails. `b` cannot be then matched with `h`, nor `e`, nor `r`, nor another `r`, nor `y`. Note if you change the last `y?` to `b?`, you [will get a `b` in the match](https://regex101.com/r/pS6bG5/2).

If you do not use `/g` (global) flag in a JS regex, the engine will only check for one match. It will find it at the beginning - an empty string, return it and call it a day. [If you use `/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pS6bG5/1), it will check all locations, and the second match will get you the result you want. However, when you use `String#match()` with `/g` based regex, you will lose the captured substrings. Use `RegExp#exec()` to be able to access these submatches.

Note that `/(c?)(h?)(e?)(r?)(r?)(y)/` gives you a match because the last `y` is *obligatory* and the pattern can no longer match an empty string. Thus, when the engine sees `b` in `berry`, it fails the match, goes on to check the next location before `e`, and finds the match there. Thus, no `/g` is necessary in this situation.